# ISV - can I ask tax-related questions on Programmers?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition

I'm an Independent Software Vender.

The ["FAQ" page on Programmer's Meta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) states that appropriate questions include "freelancing and business concerns".

1. Can I ask for advice on tax-related matters on Programmers?
2. If not, is there a place on the SE network where I can?
3. My question is specifically about Apple's App Store and some tax details there. Would that change the answer to either #1 or #2 above?

Comment: Talked this over with another mod, and, depending on the level of specificity needed, you might try [Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have to say, I'm ticked that someone down-voted my question. The "About" page on Programmer's Meta states that appropriate questions include "freelancing and business concerns". My question could certainly fall in that category. Look, if the answer to my question is "No", that's fine (and I have politely voted accordingly). But the question is a valid one, which I suspect many other people will have as well.

Comment: Don't put too much stock in votes on meta: they work [a little differently than they do on the main sites](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences). Meta down-votes usually mean disagreement with the subject of the post: in this case, that tax questions could be on-topic here. It's a bit confusing, but your question was valid and clearly presented.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that. The accepted status of answers and the number of votes on answers already (rightly) exist as means to provide that information. Votes on the question itself should not represent some indication of the correct answer to a question.

Comment: Are you familiar with [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/)? That's where SE did its meta-discussion before they created meta sites like this one, and its meta culture comes from that: people up-voting things they want developers/moderators to change/fix/address and down-voting things they don't want changed or considered. System works okay for bugs, feature requests, and discussions, but definitely breaks down for support issues.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Well for support issues, I guess down voting means something along the lines of "I don't want moderators / team to lose much sleep over this, it isn't really important".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No, that'd be off-topic here: Programmers's expertise is in software development, not accounting or tax law.
2. Legal issues like this don't fit into the Stack Exchange model very well: they almost always rely on knowing your specific situation, and people trying to Google that information later on are either going to be misled at best or be given harmful advice at worst.

   However, you might want to try over at [Personal Finance & Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com): they're likely not going to entertain specifics, but they might be able to help with general tax issues. I'd ask on their [meta-discussion site](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com) first, like you did here.
3. It would not.

Stack Exchange can do a lot of things, but unfortunately, we're not a substitute for a good CPA. :)

Comment: who's CPA? Chartered Patent Attorney? Certified Public Accountant? Collaborative Pissing Attacker? :)

Comment: @gnat [Certified Public Accountant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Public_Accountant)

Answer (score -1):

it would be on topic is the tax related part was unrelated to the rest of the question. Like "should i keep all tax related logic in a separate module?" or something.

Comment: Then it is not really a tax/law related problem though, it is a business logic problem ;-)